# Incorrect ehcache statistics: hits+misses == 0

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, annotations, ehcache

I have a problem where `net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager` appears returns invalid statistics.

I'm using `ehcache-core v2.3.2` (latest version) with [`ehcache-spring-annotations`](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/).

**The problem** is that `getMemoryStoreObjectCount` returns **1** object while both `getCacheHits` and `getCacheMisses` returns **0**. Isn't the total count supposed to be *`hits + misses`* ?

The unit test below should illustrate the problem (it's applied to an *empty* database):

```
@Test
public void testCache() {
    Entity e = ..
    dao.storeEntity(e);
    dao.getEntity(e);
    assertEquals(1, cache.getStatistics().getMemoryStoreObjectCount()); // ok
    assertEquals(0, cache.getStatistics().getCacheHits()); // ok
    assertEquals(1, cache.getStatistics().getCacheMisses()); // fails due to 0

}
```

---

For completeness I include all essential configuration:

Spring config

```
<ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" />
<bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
```

ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache>
     <defaultCache eternal="false" maxElementsInMemory="1000"
        overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
        timeToLiveSeconds="600" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
</ehcache>
```

dao

```
@Cacheable(keyGenerator=@KeyGenerator(name="StringCacheKeyGenerator"))
public Entity getEntity(Serializable key) {
    return // sql ... 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Would you mind posting your code regarding how you derived the "cache" variable in your JUnit test from the Spring configuration?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem by setting the following properties in `net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCache`:

```
  cache.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
  cache.setStatisticsAccuracy(Statistics.STATISTICS_ACCURACY_GUARANTEED);
```

Comment: perhaps the 2nd is not required though.

Comment: @Bozho, probably not, but in test it won't matter.

Comment: yes. I just thought it's worth mentioning. Anyway, the answer formed for me, so +1.

Answer (score 17):

Add **statistics="true"** to your ehcache.xml, it's usually better to keep your configuration changes outside your code.

```
<ehcache>
     <defaultCache ... statistics="true" />
...
</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `<defaultCache ... statistics="true" />` works greatly
in contrast with the old way cache.setStatisticsEnabled(true); that needs the lower version of ehcache (core and etc).